# Using rxjava I can't get retrofit off the main thread

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

Simplified code is below, s is a subscriber that matches the return type of my end point. No matter what I do I get a network on main thread exception. Some tutorials don't even mention threads here saying retrofit handles it automatically when you use rxjava, but things seem to be going the other way for me, I can't seem to get it off the main thread.

```
PostInterface p = getRestAdapter().create(PostInterface.class);

p.getFeedForUser()
    .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(s);
```

Edit:

I have also tried this code (posted below):

```
p.getFeedForUser()
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .subscribe(s);
```

I have also tried it without subscribing on a thread. I get the networking on main thread exception every time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should `observeOn` in main thread, `subscribe` on new thread

```
p.getFeedForUser()
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .subscribe(s);
```

Comment: And also, you can just skip the `subscribeOn` because that is what Retrofit does by default.

Comment: @david.mihola, so thanks for your response. If it's possible, can you please give me a link when I can read about it? Because I read somewhere that retrofits add `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())`, but may be I'm wrong

Comment: Interestingly I cannot find it in the official documentation at http://square.github.io/retrofit/. But I have been using Retrofit with Rx without a `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` for some time now without any problems. Also there is Jake Wharton's example app, where he also does it like that: https://github.com/JakeWharton/u2020/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jakewharton/u2020/ui/trending/TrendingView.java

Comment: retrofit doesnt use any subscribeOn by default, it uses it's internal scheduler to execute request, but it's not done via Rx subscribeOn method, also not 100% sure about that, but this behavior may change in future so i'd use subscribeOn anyway

Comment: I changed to this code and am still getting the networking on main thread exception.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was using an older version of Retrofit, as soon as I switched to a newer version it started working properly.